# In FontForge I want to alter the 9 to have a straight stalk without affecting the 6

Tags: fontforge

I'm using FontForge to adjust some characters in a font. Mostly this works well. However when I edit the digit 9 (to give it a straight stalk), the digit 6 is affected too, as if the 6 is defined as a 9 rotated 180°.

What do I need to do in order that the 6 becomes independant of the 9, and continues to display as a curved 6 after I have changed the 9?

I have tried copying the 6, clearing the 6, and then pasting it back; but that does not solve the problem.

I do not know what the correct terminology is for the link/reference between the 6 and the 9.  Neither do I know how to see what glyphs are based on which other glyphs.

I have experimented editing the 6; the 6 glyph is displayed in the editor window with the word 'nine' above it suggesting that it is based on the 9.   When editing the 6, the 9 does not change.

I imagine there are 2 solutions:
1. Somehow make the 6 independant from the 9.
2. Basing the 9 one the 6 instead of the other way around, allowing me to edit the 9 without unintended consequences.

When answering, please be very specific with explanation and provide a step-by-step list of instructions (I am not a font designer, and I am new to FontForge).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found an answer, based on a clue I found in a Manual for TeX users.   The 6 is a 'reference' to the 9.  FontForger's 'Paste Into' actually means 'Paste Reference' (which is presumably how the 6 was created).   By copying the 9 and pasting it into the 6 using ordinary 'Paste' (which is 'Paste Glyph') I achieved a separate symbol for the 6.   Rotating the new glyph 180° gives me the separate 6 the right way around.   The 9 can now be edited without affecting the 6.

But I do find another problem.   I'm using the lower case q as the basis for the straight-stalked 9.   The q has 2 logical parts, the stalk, and the 'c'.   The 'c' is too big vertically.   How can I scale it down vertically while keeping the vertical stroke widths the same (and not altering any of the horizontal dimensions)?

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510831/how-can-i-scale-a-glyph-down-vertically-while-keeping-the-vertical-stroke-widths

Answer (score 0):

The '6' is a reference to the '9' glyph. Open the '6' glyph and Edit > Unlink Reference (or ctrl-U).