# How can I scale a glyph down vertically while keeping the vertical stroke widths the same (and not altering any of the horizontal dimensions)?

Tags: scale, stroke, fontforge

I'm using FontForge.   I'm modifying the lower case q to make a straight-stalked 9.   The q has 2 logical parts, the stalk, and the 'c'.   The 'c' is too big vertically.   How can I scale it down vertically while keeping the vertical stroke widths the same (and not altering any of the horizontal dimensions)?

I'm a novice with FontForge, so please spell out your explanation and provide step-by-step instructions.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to decrease the x-height of the 'q' without changing stroke widths.
Font-forge provides a built-in tool to achieve this: Element > Styles > Change X-Height. You might like to experiment with this, but in practice it gives you very little control over the results and I would rarely use it.

Instead I would achieve this by directly modifying the nodes of the paths.
First, I would ensure that InterpolateCPsOnMotion is enabled. Double-click the pointer tool in your toolbox to access this setting.

[image]

This will help ensure that curves scale correctly (rather than distort) as you move control points. Now, I would select the nodes at the top and sides of the bowl of the q:

[image]

and use the down arrow key to move them down about half the distance you wish to decrease the height by. Then I would deselect the nodes at the side of the bowl:

[image]

and lower the remaining nodes the rest of the distance:

[image]

You will need to check the resulting appearance and possibly make tweaks to get it perfect. Note that this or any scaling technique can subtly distort the axis of modulated strokes, which you may wish to correct.

This technique presupposes that nodes are sensibly placed at the vertical and horizontal extrema of the bowl, and that you don't have extra nodes between these extrema. If you are not in this happy situation, you can add extrema by ctrl-shift-x and you can remove surplus nodes by selecting them and ctrl-m. If you can't remove extra nodes without significantly changing the shape of the bowl, you'll just have to modify these nodes by eye.

Another point: you say you're working from a "c". I'm not sure whether you just mean the C-shape of the bowl of the q, or whether you mean you are copying the actual glyph 'c'. Note that it is rare that the bowl of a 'q' will have exactly the same shape and weight as a 'c'. Typically the stroke will be somewhat lighter to achieve the right visual grey, and especial care will be taken where it intersects the stem. Often the two shapes will differ substantially.